# Can I solve the problem with Routes in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've a problem with a routing in React. I have 3 element: app.tsx for main page the app, routerwrapper.tsx for routing the components(pages), 1 page called summary.tsx, the page changes, but I inherit everything I have on the apptsx. How do I solve? I don't want to display app.tsx items but only present on summary. thanks. solve the problem please When I try to insert this in app.tsx

```
return (
  <div className="app">
    <div className="content">
      <RouterWrapper />
      <RouterWrapper />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to clarify in more detail what the issue or problem is, and include a more complete [mcve] so we can see what the code does?